# Problem with NVIDIA GeForce4 MX 4000

Tags: drivers, nvidia

**Hi!**

Is this card working with Ubuntu. Is there any driver? When I installed Ubuntu 12.04 there was a black screen.

Thx, Akitoru

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To install the driver, follow these instructions:

1. Boot into recovery
2. Run `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install Nvidia-current` in a Terminal
3. Reboot
4. Profit!

---

1. If you cannot boot into GRUB, boot into a live CD
2. Open a Terminal
3. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install boot-repair && sudo boot-repair`
4. Choose the recommended repair
5. Follow the instructions
6. Reboot
7. Follow the instructions to install the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: OK, thanx a lot, but: How to "Boot into recovery"? Sry, I'm new :)

Comment: When your computer boots, the GRUB bootloader should pop up. Choose Ubuntu Recovery Console or something of the like.

Comment: Ok, but if I will have only Ubuntu on my comp?

Comment: No. boot-repair fixes GRUB, which is used to load Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: I know. But I will have only Ubuntu. :)